# Como deixar reta a borda da linha desenhada com Graphics em Java?

Tags: java, awt

Fiz um programa que traça linhas na tela, porem a linha fica muito deformada (imagem 2) em determinadas ligações. Queria saber se tem jeito de deixar reta (imagem 1) a borda da linha em qualquer que seja a inclinação dela.

Estou usando `Graphics2D`.

[image: imagens]

Answer (score 2):

Use a [classe `RenderingHints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html):

```
private static final RenderingHints HINTS = new RenderingHints(null);
static {
    HINTS.put(KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    HINTS.put(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); 
    HINTS.put(KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY); 
    HINTS.put(KEY_INTERPOLATION, VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC); 
    HINTS.put(KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHints(HINTS);

    // Prossiga com seu desenho aqui.
}
```

Todas essas chaves e valores são adicionadas com `import static java.awt.RenderingHints.*`. O mais importante é o `KEY_ANTIALIASING` e o `VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON` que ativa o anti-aliasing.

Para mais detalhes, veja [o TCC que fiz nessa área em 2007](https://www.academia.edu/24862059/Manipula%C3%A7%C3%A3o_e_desenho_em_componentes_com_Java2D).